# Outlook 2013 - VBA - reply in line

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba

I have written a small script to automatically select the first autocorrect option. It works when, in 2013, I write a new email or "pop out" an email. However - it does not work when I reply "in line" - e.g. per the right window in the image below.

In VBA - how does one find/select text in a new email when once is in the "work in line" mode?

[image]

Below is my current code

```
Sub Spellcheckoutlook()

Dim oSE As Word.Range
Dim oSC
With ActiveInspector
    If .IsWordMail And .EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        For Each oSE In .WordEditor.Range.SpellingErrors
            Set oSC = oSE.GetSpellingSuggestions
            If oSC.Count > 0 Then
            oSE.Text = oSC(1)
            End If
        Next oSE
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You code works with Outlook Inspector (a separate message window). In order to be able to manipulate the right-side preview pane text, you need to use the **ActiveExplorer**'s **ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor** property like this:

```vb
Set Editor = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor
If Editor Is Nothing And Not ActiveInspector Is Nothing Then
    Set Editor = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
End If
If Not Editor Is Nothing Then
    ' Do your stuff for Editor.Range ...
End If
```